# Django How to retrieve relating data with hitting database much less in situation of two tables with m2m relationship

Tags: django, database, many-to-many

Let's say there are two tables.

```
#table A : Category
class Category
    title = models.CharField()

#table B : Devices
class Devices
    device_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField()
```

[image]

If I want to see table like above.

simply I can make code using `category = Category.objects.get(id=From A to E)` `category.devices_set.all()`, then show each devices by Forloop.

but problem is that you have to query individually for A, B, C, D, E. If you have more category, it seems you need to hit database more to retrieve devices relating to each category.

I think the best way is retrieve all data from two tables at once. And then make table like above with JavaScripts.

Is there any easy way to do that without hitting database many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is what you are looking for.

> Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings') now each time self.toppings.all() is called, instead of having to go to the database for the items, it will find them in a prefetched QuerySet cache that was populated in a single query.

So you can do this:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(id__in=[A, B, C, D, E]).prefetch_related('devices_set')
for category in categories:
    devices = category.devices_set.all()
    for device in devices:
        do_something
```

Comment: **prefetch_related** is the key, and should be used everytime you are trying to do a separate lookup for each relationship.

Comment: What if you want to send categories in JSON type? If you use serializers.serialize('json' categories) send only category instances but not any queryset relating to devices_set. Is there way to send categories and relating devices with devices_set queryset in JSON type?

Comment: @Jayground sorry I cannot advise you something useful. Just look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/ it says you can get related object for the model which defines relation. So try do following: `serializers.serialize('json' devices)` or look at Django Rest Framework.